# How do I stop configuration parameters from using the same values each time I create a partner

Tags: openerp

I am currently working on implementing OpenERP for the hospital where I work. The hospital has it's own chart of accounts with many income, expense, receiveable and payable accounts. I noticed that each time I create a partner by default it creates properties  "property_account_payable" and "property_account_receivable" and assigns a default account value to it. These values are not the same for all the partners on the system. Is there a way I can stop it from assigning default values and instead assign these values myself? The easiest way I found was to go to the ir.property table in the db and change some values there. This is not very good because when the others start creating partners, I won't want them to have any form of access to the database

Answer (score 2):

Those properties appear on the Accounting tab of the Partner screen. They are hidden when you use the simplified view. See the tip at the top of [this manual page](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/book/6/6_16_Sales/6_16_Sales_control.html) for instructions on changing to the extended view.